# How to detect when the program is idle?

Tags: c#

For example, how does the program detect when the user hasn't used it for 5 minutes?

Comment: Command line? WPF? Winforms? Webforms?

Comment: Do you mean program (A) detect when it, (A), hasn't been used for a while or do you mean program (A) detect when another program, (B), hasn't been used for a while?

Comment: Winforms , I need webform - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForms there is an Application.Idle event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx

Comment: Guess it's better for this case than what I've proposed. :)