# Program wasn't in use for 2 minutes

Tags: c#, winforms, popup

I wan't to popup a specific form when the user didn't use the program for 2 minutes,
let's say.

Means: When the application run, and the user didn't press any key / any button / didn't move the cursor at all for 2 minutes, I want the application to detect it and to show an instance of one of the form's window.
I use winform application in c#.

How can I do it?
Tal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6282298/731323 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/6282298/731323

Answer (score 5):

See the `Application.Idle` event and this related question:

[How to detect when the program is idle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422620/how-to-detect-when-the-program-is-idle)

There is also a detailed example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Application_Idle.aspx

Comment: well the examples I saw are much complicated than what I mean, but most of them has no attitude to the timer intervals. Do you have any simple example for me? Do I have to use 2 events: the idle event and the timer event?

Comment: Yes .. you have to put some effort into this yourself! Creating a timer and handling events form it will only take 1 minute to code!

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm a beginner... It doesn't work. Don't you have any simple example for me? please??

Answer (score 0):

Does your application does itself some work with out users intervention? In such case, you cant get the idle time at all.

May be use timers would be a best option in such cases!!